# WillAnimateRotation is not called in Subviews of Monotouch?

Tags: xamarin.ios, orientation

I have the RootViewController added to the Window  and only that UIViewController class WillAnimateRotation is called.

All the other UIViewControllers WillAnimateRotation is not automatically called.

But I am calling them manually.  Because of that manual call I am facing lot of problem in Orientation.

Is there any way to call them automatically when the Each View is turned.

Answer (score 0):

That probably is because you inserted at least one ViewController that does not implement the should-rotate method.